# WooCommerce - not linking to products using "single product shortcode"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to use the WooCommerce shortcode

```
[product id="99"]
```

However I would like to have both the product image and product name itself not link to the individual product page. All I want is the "Add to Cart" button working as intended but nothing else being clickable.

Is this possible? What template would I need to edit?

This doesn't need to be applicable to only a specific shortcode if it's easier. I never want to have people be able to get to product pages at all, so if there is a "global" way to do this, it'll work too.

Comment: Did you want to display only "Add to cart" button based on product id? Am i right?

Comment: No, I want to display everything, including the image and product name. However image and product name should not be linked to anything. Only the add to cart button should have the normal link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it the logic you need to do in your functions.php, I have created a custom shortcode to get the product as you explained.

```
function get_c_product($atts){

    $params = shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => '0',
    ), $atts );
    $args = array('post_type'=>'product','post__in'=>array($params['id']));
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $return = '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $_product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
            $return .= '<li>' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail() . '</li>';
            $return .= '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
            $return .= '<li>' . do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id='.get_the_ID().']') . '</li>';
        }
        $return .= '</ul>';
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
    return $return;
}

add_shortcode('product_custom','get_c_product');
```

Then use the shortcode like this : `echo do_shortcode('[product_custom id="99"]');` or `[product_custom id="99"]`

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked exactly like I wanted it to.

Comment: Glad to help you :)